# Restore Transaction For inapp purchase in version 2 Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, restore

I'm using version 2 for inapp purchase.I resered this document http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/api.html.In restore transaction i have sent

> BillingHelper.restoreTransactionInformation(BillingSecurity.generateNonce())

I have received the response_code and request_id.After that it is not calling the function PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED as mentioned in the document.I have simple received response and request id.I don't how to proceed further.I need to get the product details of purchase items.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks In Advance:)